# Unusual behaviour when select multiple item of select element by jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I select multiple items items of select by the following jquery code.

```
$.map($("[id*='lstWeekDays'] option"), function(e) {
if (jQuery.inArray($.trim($(e).val()), item1) != -1) {

    if (!$(":selected", e).is(':checked')) {
            $(e).attr("selected", true);
        }
    }
});
```

By this, in option tag of select element selected="selected" attribute add.

```
<select style="width:188px;" id="lstWeekDays" multiple="multiple"  size="4">
    <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
    <option value="Monday" selected="selected">Monday</option>
    <option value="Tuesday" selected="selected">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>

</select>
```

Now when i select other element by UI then then this attribute does not remove from HTML,but they get deselected from the select List.And when I try to Select item of select list by jquery again,then items are not selected. I know the question is bit confusing.So please ask me if you have any confusion

Comment: `$(":selected", e).is(':checked')` are you sure there isn't a better way?

Comment: ya it looks pretty weird,i am surely changing this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$(e).prop("selected", true);`.

`.attr()` sets default attributes on the element while `.prop()` changes the "running" attribute.